# type error while i was doing the Rl project of super mario bros by Nicholas Renotte

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Setup game:

```
env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0', apply_api_compatibility=True, render_mode="human")
env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)

# Create a flag - restart or not
done = True
# Loop through each frame in the game
for step in range(100000): 
    # Start the game to begin with 
    if done: 
        # Start the gamee
        env.reset()
    # Do random actions
    state, reward, done, truncated , info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    # Show the game on the screen
    env.render()
# Close the game
env.close()
```

Install pytorch:

```
!pip install torch==1.10.1+cu113 torchvision==0.11.2+cu113 torchaudio===0.10.1+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
Install stable baselines for RL stuff
!pip install stable-baselines3[extra]

Import Frame Stacker Wrapper and GrayScaling Wrapper
from gym.wrappers import GrayScaleObservation
Import Vectorization Wrappers
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import VecFrameStack, DummyVecEnv
Import Matplotlib to show the impact of frame stacking
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

1. Create the base environment

`env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0')`

2. Simplify the controls

   env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)
3. Grayscale

   env = GrayScaleObservation(env, keep_dim=True)
4. Wrap inside the Dummy Environment`

   env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
5. Stack the frames`

   env = VecFrameStack(env, 4, channels_order='last')`

   state = env.reset()

ERROR :-

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 1
----> 1 state = env.reset()

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\vec_env\vec_frame_stack.py:41, in VecFrameStack.reset(self)
     37 def reset(self) -> Union[np.ndarray, Dict[str, np.ndarray]]:
     38     """
     39     Reset all environments
     40     """
---> 41     observation = self.venv.reset()  # pytype:disable=annotation-type-mismatch
     42     observation = self.stacked_obs.reset(observation)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
     43     return observation

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\vec_env\dummy_vec_env.py:76, in DummyVecEnv.reset(self)
     74 def reset(self) -> VecEnvObs:
     75     for env_idx in range(self.num_envs):
---> 76         obs, self.reset_infos[env_idx] = self.envs[env_idx].reset(seed=self._seeds[env_idx])
     77         self._save_obs(env_idx, obs)
     78     # Seeds are only used once

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\shimmy\openai_gym_compatibility.py:112, in GymV26CompatibilityV0.reset(self, seed, options)
    110 super().reset(seed=seed)
    111 # Options are ignored
--> 112 return self.gym_env.reset(seed=seed, options=options)
...
    378     """Resets the environment, returning a modified observation using :meth:`self.observation`."""
--> 379     obs, info = self.env.reset(**kwargs)
    380     return self.observation(obs), info

TypeError: JoypadSpace.reset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'seed'
```

it should work as the tutorial shows`